# Hide only parent class of the child in loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've this loop in WordPress that displays post.

```
<div class="parent-div" id="unuqueIdHereForEachBlock">
 <div class="child-1"></div>
 <div class="child-2">
    <div class="sub-child">

    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This 'parent-div' is in loop and it repeats 20-30 times for each post. For some of the posts, sub-child div would have no content, and in that case I want to hide 'child-1' div just for that particular post.

Solution in jQuery, JavaScript or PHP is fine.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code that generates this content, it's better to not generate it than to try and remove it later.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following

```js
$(".parent-div").each((i,e) => {
if(!$(e).find(".child-2 .sub-child").text().trim()) $(e).find(".child-1").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-div" id="unuqueIdHereForEachBlock">
 <div class="child-1">Text 1</div>
 <div class="child-2">
    <div class="sub-child">

    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="parent-div" id="unuqueIdHereForEachBlock">
 <div class="child-1">Text 2</div>
 <div class="child-2">
    <div class="sub-child">
        Some text
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, 
Your solution worked but it didn't hide all of the posts with no text inside 'sub-child' div. Only first few posts got hidden.

Comment: @SunilPatel - It should not happen unless there is something else in the html. Can you please share the html of elements that failed?

Comment: here's the screenshot of html code -> https://imgur.com/a/tArjCUe
and here's the copy your script -> https://pastebin.com/u3C0EMiB
Thanks.

Comment: @SunilPatel - You are having same `id` (**estate-card**) for the elements. Use `class` selector

Comment: Nikhil, you're legend. It worked. Apologies for the ID mix up.

Comment: @SunilPatel - hahaha.. Thank you. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jQuery, where you can iterate over each parent div and check for text. if text length is zero then hide child div

```
$(function(){
  $(".parent-div").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).find(".child-2 > .sub-child").text();
     if(text.length==0) {
        $(this).find(".child-1").hide();
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself clearly. '.parent-div' and it's immediate child(ren) would have text/sub nodes within. I want to hide the 'child-1' div ONLY IF there's no text/sub nodes inside 'sub-child' div.

Comment: @SunilPatel, I have updated my post after reading your comment. Please check

Comment: Hi @Bhushan, I tried updated code too, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: are parent elements getting add dynamically? can you recreate this on jsfiddle or code snipped?